# Calculator example / link between JS and HTML element

Tags: calculator

I m doing a practice example for a calculator, and I don t understand following part:

this is what it looks like

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const display = document.querySelector("#display");

 for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
   buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
     let number = buttons[i].getAttribute("data-num");
    display.value += number;
   });
 }
```

```html
    <section>
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="display" />
      </form>
      <div class="btns">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="+">+</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="-">-</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="/">/</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="*">*</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="0">0</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="1">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="2">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="3">3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="4">4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="5">5</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="6">6</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="7">7</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="8">8</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-num="9">9</button>

        <button type="button" class="e-btn" data-num="=">=</button>
        <button type="button" class="c-btn" data-num="C">C</button>
      </div>
    </section>
```

I think I understand the for loop and the idea behind all of this. I assume the const "**buttons**" in `JS` is turned into an `array(?),`

I think I get that, but how is this linked to the **individual button** in the `HTML` since there is no `ID` or separate `class`, the `array` is only created for the `JS` (?), in `HTML` this is just the same `button` all over the place.

how is, for example, the `buttons`[5] `eventlistener` linked to the button that represents the button "**0**" in `HTML`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an old expression that goes, "It's calculators all the way down." Nobody knows where it comes from, but its insight into the physical world is astonishing. For instance, here you are calculating the elements of a calculator whose visible elements are calculated by a web browser. That web browser runs on code which was compiled through calculation within an operating system, which was compiled through another calculation using a CPU, which is itself a calculator and stands for Calculator Please Use. All of this was devised by a human brain, which is the highest form of calculator other than the TI-89, which can run Doom.

Anyway, back to the question at hand, HTML elements do not need an `id` or `class` to exist as separate from each other. Those are just means of locating them. Even without an `id`, every button still exists on the screen as an independent thing. Given that, `document.querySelectorAll(".btn")` returns an array-like object called a `NodeList` that can be iterated over. Each element in that `NodeList` can be identified through its index (in other words, in this example, `buttons[i]` where `i` is the index into the list).

An `id` is useful when you want to be able to locate the element by itself. A `class` is useful when you want to be able to identify a group of related elements (`btn`) in this case. `document.querySelectorAll(".btn")` says "Give me all of the elements with the class `btn`."

Comment: But doesn't the HTML element have to be linked to the actionlistener created in JS at some point? I understand, that HTML elements can exist without an ID, but if i click on the button, which is an HTML element (?) - how does it know which actionlistener in JS it is linked to / has to be triggered? I fear i m misunderstanding something very basic here....

Comment: `addEventListener` is that link. Each iteration through the loop has a pointer to one of the buttons. That pointer is used to add an event listener. Since `addEventListener` takes a function, each iteration is creating a new function that will be run on a click event, and that is being associated with the element at that pointer. So you end up with `n` listeners, each with its own link to a distinct HTML element, where `n` is equal to `buttons.length`.

Comment: If i get it right the for loop does only create something like this :  buttons[0].addEventListener("click, function () {
   let number = "+"
   display.value += number;
   
   )} for every button. But the buttons[0] only refers to the NodeList from JavaScript, how does that translate to the "+" button in HTML? In HTML there is no NodeList, where this "+" button is listed as the button number 0, thats what i don t understand.

Comment: HTML is like the variable declaration. It tells the browser to create the button HTML element. You don't have to care how that thing is stored, whether it's in HTML, Javascript, or browser code. The important thing is that the browser has a button somewhere and it lets you reference it using Javascript. When you add the event listener, it's adding it to the button somewhere in its memory. When you click the button, it knows how to find that thing and run its listener.

Comment: Ok this idea that HTML is somewhat like the variable declaration does help me to wrap my head around this, even tho i still don t fully understand it, I think that is ok for now. Thanks, you helped me a lot!